# Sending credentials with params - PUT -Firefox

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am logged in on Walmart's website, and I have a shopping cart. When I add items to my cart, I make an `PUT` request

PUT request picture - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRXxD.png

and just like that, I add an item to my cart.

Now, to get to the point of this post. I am writing an extension for Firefox, and the main thing is the `content_script`.  Script's main function is to make the same request as if I would click on `Add to cart` button on Walmart page, but I don't know how to send all that credentials that can be found in Request Headers.

Obviously, I have the rights to send a proper request, but that's only by clicking on the button, and my goal is to send it via `content_script` (or background script) with my extension.

`content_script.js`

```
(function(){
    var params = {"cartItems":[{"offerId":"8E5AE39B44CD467DAC4AAA3A0042110F","quantity":3}]}
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:

            var res = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

            console.log(res);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("PUT", "https://grocery.walmart.com/api/v3/cart/:GCRT/items", true);
    xhttp.withCredentials = true;
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(params));

})();
```

As you can see, I have `xhttp.withCredentials` set to `true` but that doesn't work, because I don't get anything on my console.

The proper question would be: how to prove to Walmart that this request is still coming from my PC and my account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending more headers included from that picture, but still, I don't think you can send `cookie` key-value pair because it is forbidden in `XMLHttpRequest`.